# contact form 7 javascript and wpcf7_before_send_mail action

Tags: javascript, plugin-contact-form-7

Hi folks i've created a function to redirect the submitted form to my paiement provider for online payment. with the "wpcf7_before_send_mail" action.

The function is working well except that i need to deactivate javascript for the form otherwise my submit button is not working.

here is the code of my function:

```
<?php

add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_1redirectPostfinance'); 
function wpcf7_1redirectPostfinance ($cf7 ) {
$form_id = $cf7->id();
// apply redirection to pf from the following cf7 form ids
if ($form_id == 13570 || $form_id == 9483 || $form_id == 2201): 
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
if ( $submission ) {
    $formdata = $submission->get_posted_data();
}
$my_current_lang = apply_filters( 'wpml_current_language', NULL );
    if ($my_current_lang == 'fr') {
        $lang='fr_FR';
    } elseif ($my_current_lang == 'de') { 
       $lang='de_DE';
    } elseif ($my_current_lang == 'it') { 
        $lang='it_IT';  
    } else {$lang='de_DE';}


// Form data to send to postfinance (ogone)
$form = array(
    'PSPID' => 'my_psp_id',
    'ORDERID' => $formdata['refenfant'].' '.$formdata['menu-306'],
    'AMOUNT' => $formdata['wert']*100,
    'CURRENCY' => 'CHF',
    'LANGUAGE' => $lang,
    'CN' => $formdata['vorname'].' '.$formdata['nachname'],
    'EMAIL' => $formdata['email'],
    'ACCEPTURL' => 'my accept url',
    'DECLINEURL' => 'my decline url',
    'EXCEPTIONURL' => 'my exeption url',
    'CANCELURL' => 'my cancel url',
);
//generate hash string
$arrayToHash = array();
foreach ($form as $key => $value) {
    if ($value != '' ) {
        $arrayToHash[] = strtoupper($key) . '=' . $value . 'my hash value';
    }
}
asort($arrayToHash);
$stringToHash = implode('', $arrayToHash);
$hashedString = sha1($stringToHash);

?>
//send the form to postfinance
<html>
    <head><title>Redirecting to Postfinance...</title></head>
    <body>
        <form action='https://e-payment.postfinance.ch/ncol/test/orderstandard.asp' method='post' name="pf_for_contact_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="PSPID" value="<?php echo $form['PSPID']; ?>"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="ORDERID" value="<?php echo $form['ORDERID']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" value="<?php echo $form['AMOUNT']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="CURRENCY" value="<?php echo $form['CURRENCY']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="LANGUAGE" value="<?php echo $form['LANGUAGE']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="CN" value="<?php echo $form['CN']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="EMAIL" value="<?php echo $form['EMAIL']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="ACCEPTURL" value="<?php echo $form['ACCEPTURL']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="DECLINEURL" value="<?php echo $form['DECLINEURL']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="EXCEPTIONURL" value="<?php echo $form['EXCEPTIONURL']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="CANCELURL" value="<?php echo $form['CANCELURL']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="SHASIGN" value="<?php echo $hashedString; ?>">
        </form>
        Form ID: <?php echo $form_id; ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
           document.pf_for_contact_form.submit();
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
endif;  
}

?>
```

Do you have any suggestion ?
When checking the code inspector or console, i do not have any js errors.
My bet is that the submit action is not triggered but i don't know why.

thanks for your help

Comment: 0 I went down the Javascript route, which works... but you then don't have access to the submitted variables (at least I couldn't see how you would). Here I have ported my Javascript code across to PHP code. You can access any hidden or displayed inputs in the form and use them to build the URL. There is one required trick to do the redirect in PHP rather than Javascript, which is that you have to turn off the CF7 Javascript as per the doc. Put this in your wp-config.php: define('WPCF7_LOAD_JS', false);